# Aging and Hormone Levels

Tags: endocrinology

Hormone levels in humans decrease with age. The effects are especially detrimental for women after menopause.
Biologists state that turtles do not exhibit most of the phenomena related to aging. For example telemore shortening does not happen in certain turtle species.
Here is my question:
Do turtle hormone levels decrease with age as in humans?

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense, as men do not undergo menopause.